# @here/maps-api-for-javascript not working next js

Tags: javascript, next.js, here-api

I am trying to figure out why `@here/maps-api-for-javascript` is not working in next js and throwing the below error:

```
import H from "@here/maps-api-for-javascript";

export default H;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [export default data SyntaxError: Unexpected token export during bulding on next.js using typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66775173/export-default-data-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export-during-bulding-on-next)? Try using `next-transpile-modules` to transpile `@here/maps-api-for-javascript`.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it broke the `self` reference within the package.

Answer (score 0):

### Please try the below snippet and refer to the following guide for more details:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.29.0/dev_guide/topics/react-practices.html

```
import React from 'react'; 

import H from "@here/maps-api-for-javascript"; 

export default class Map extends React.Component { 

  constructor(props) { 

    super(props); 

    // the reference to the container 

    this.ref = React.createRef(); 

    // reference to the map 

    this.map = null; 

  } 

  
  componentDidMount() { 

    if (!this.map) { 

      // instantiate a platform, default layers and a map as usual 

      const platform = new H.service.Platform({ 

        apikey: '{YOUR_API_KEY}' 

      }); 

      const layers = platform.createDefaultLayers(); 

      const map = new H.Map( 

        this.ref.current, 

        layers.vector.normal.map, 

        { 

          pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio, 

          center: {lat: 0, lng: 0}, 

          zoom: 2, 

        }, 

      ); 

      this.map = map; 

    } 

  } 

  
  render() { 

    return ( 

      <div 

        style={{ width: '300px', height:'300px' }} 

        ref={this.ref} 

      /> 

    ) 

  } 

}
```

Comment: While this may be fine with regular React, won't this still cause the same issue in a Next.js app? You're still importing `@here/maps-api-for-javascript` on the server-side (top level import). Maybe moving to a dynamic import inside `componentDidMount` could fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The way to resolve this issue is with a [Dynamic Import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) with no SSR. If you follow the [Using React](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.29.0/dev_guide/topics/react-practices.html) guide provided by HERE, you will need to import the Map component as follows:

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

function App() {
  const Map = dynamic(() => import("./Map"), {
    ssr: false
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <Map />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Note that `next/dynamic` can't be used inside of React rendering, it needs to be declared at the top level of the module for preloading to work.