# Is there a way to make a realtime notification with nextjs using pusher-js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pusher-js

I've read the docs of `pusher-js` to make realtime notification with Next.js, but I keep getting error when importing the package like this (as docs says)

```js
import * as PusherPushNotifications from "@pusher/push-notifications-web";
```

The error says: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`.

[image]

Is there any way to create notifications with Next.js and solve this error? Or should I use another way?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [export default data SyntaxError: Unexpected token export during bulding on next.js using typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66814697/1870780)? Try using [`next-transpile-modules`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules) to transpile `@pusher/push-notifications-web`.

Comment: @juliomalves thank you very much, it solved the problem and pusher says it's now connected .